# IOS: how to show completion result of social framework

Tags: ios, facebook

I tried to use social framework for Facebook in IOS with swift. And I tried the following code, however I can't show the alert window...

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
        var mes: String = ""
        let shareWindow: SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        //configure initial text
        shareWindow.setInitialText("XXX")
        self.presentViewController(shareWindow, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //handle the result of this share
        shareWindow.completionHandler = { result -> Void in
            let getResult = result as SLComposeViewControllerResult;
            switch(getResult.rawValue) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled.rawValue:
                mes = "Cancelled!"
            case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done.rawValue:
                mes = "Successfully Posted!"
            default:
                mes = ""
            }
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
        if mes.isEmpty == false {
            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Facebook Post Result", message: mes, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Could someone give me a hint? Thank you so much!

Comment: Move your if statement with the alert into the ,completionHander part of the code.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that before, it's not working.

Comment: Well it won't work as it is now, put it back there and run it and debug and find out what the value of mes is.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `self.presentViewController(shareWindow, animated: true, completion: nil)` after the end of the completion handler and before the IF.